# 2 Enum с одинаковыми полями

Tags: c++

Каким образом определить 2 `enum` с одинаковыми полями?

```
enum horizontal_alignment
{
    stretch = 0x0,
    center,
    left,
    right
};

enum vertical_alignment
{
    stretch = 0x0,
    center,
    top,
    bottom
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Либо спрятать каждый `enum` в отдельный namespace или класс.

Либо использовать scoped enum

```
enum class horizontal_alignment
{
    stretch = 0x0,
    center,
    left,
    right
};

enum class vertical_alignment
{
    stretch = 0x0,
    center,
    top,
    bottom
};
```

Разумеется, обращаться к элементам таких `enum` придется с указанием полного имени `vertical_alignment::stretch`.

Comment: Я в замешательстве, какой из ответов помечать =)

Answer (score 4):

Если хотите два `enum` с одинаковыми полями, отметьте хотя бы один из них как `class`.

```
enum class horizontal_alignment
{
    stretch = 0x0,
    center,
    left,
    right
};

enum vertical_alignment
{
    stretch = 0x0,
    center,
    top,
    bottom
};
```

Comment: Это не нарушит константность?

Comment: @Yami не совсем понимаю про какую константность вы говорите. Вы про значения, которые будут присвоены элементам перечесления? Если так, то нет.